How to use Socks5 proxy on a browser?
I have an Ubuntu virtual server and I want to proxy my browser using extensions like Proxy SwitchyOmega or FoxyProxy. using the following command:
ssh -D 32145 root@ip
I ssh to the server and set the extension settings to the ssh port(32145) and set the server to localhost and socks5 , but it still doesn't work for me.
I wanted to proxy my browser with this method, but it didn't work

Use proxyfroxy extension-->proxies add  a proxy. Type socks5 hostname: 127.0.0.1 and port 32145 and save it. How enable it and reload it will work
